# Calculate mean of row using only certain columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing 5 scores for each row and then the standard deviation of these 5 scores. This was easy to calculate by using `df['std'] = df.std(axis=1, ddof=0)`.
However, when I also want to add the mean of these 5 scores, I do not know how I can exclude the `std` column in the calculation? Using `df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)` would result in pandas using the 5 scores AND the stddev in the calculation of the mean, which is obviously not what I want.

To summarise, the current `df.head` looks like this and I would like to add a column representing the mean of the 5 scores:

```
    score1  score2  score3  score4  score5  std
0   0.714286    0.689076    0.718487    0.683544    0.708861    0.013956
1   0.756303    0.704641    0.746835    0.734177    0.704641    0.021338
2   0.689076    0.722689    0.710084    0.760504    0.776371    0.032220
3   0.670833    0.704167    0.732218    0.690377    0.728033    0.023035
4   0.733333    0.758333    0.753138    0.769874    0.774059    0.014358
5   0.733333    0.825000    0.786611    0.786611    0.765690    0.029978
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `agg` instead of `df['std'] = df.std(axis=1, ddof=0)`

```
df[['mean', 'std']] = df.filter(like='score').agg((np.mean, np.std), axis=1)

# In 2 steps
df['mean'] = df.filter(like='score').agg(np.mean, axis=1)
df['std'] = df.filter(like='score').agg(lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=0), axis=1)
```

Note: I use `np.std` instead of `df.std` because ddof is 0 by default in numpy.

Comment: Thank you, this works! However, it seems like pandas overwrites this `ddof=0` default! I had to use the following to make it work:
`df['mean'] = df.filter(like='score').agg(np.mean, axis=1)` and
`df['std'] = df.filter(like='score').agg(lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=0), axis=1)`
For some reason, I could not combine these into a single line..

Comment: Could you maybe edit your answer to represent this? Than I can accept is as the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for add multiple new columns without exclude some columns:

```
df = df.assign(mean = df.mean(axis=1), std = df.std(axis=1, ddof=0))
```

Comment: This works, thanks! However I will accept @Corralien 's answer, as this is the more general solution.

Comment: @Smamorti7 - More general? Not understand why?

Comment: @Smamorti7 - In my opinion it is overcomplicated solution, but OK, it is up to you.

Comment: More general as in, it filters on the 'score', meaning that it will still work even when other columns might be apparent in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select specific columns, you can call those columns or use i.loc.

```
df["means"] = df[['score1', 'score2', 'score3', 'score4', 'score2']].mean(axis=1)
```

I haven't tried this because you did not provide a
[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! but must be close what you need.

Comment: This sadly does not seem to work, however I have accepted @Corralien 's answer! Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[4,5,6],'col3':[7,8,9]})
df['std'], df['mean'] = df.std(axis=1, ddof=0), df.mean(axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
   col1  col2  col3      std  mean
0     1     4     7  2.44949   4.0
1     2     5     8  2.44949   5.0
2     3     6     9  2.44949   6.0
```

I harness that when you do something like `x,y = a,b` in `python` firstly values to right to `=` are computed and then they are inserted in corresponding variable. This is feature that allow you do swap as follows

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a
print(a)  # 2
print(b)  # 1
```

Note: I used simpler data for my example for brevity sake

Comment: This works, thanks! However, same as in jezrael 's answer, I will accept @Corralien 's answer, as this is the more general solution!